# MongoDB Aggregation.. Counting inside an array on produce the output on javascript. using nodeJS, mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

this is my mongoose schema

```
    var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    comments: [
        {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
        }
    ]
});
```

so every user has a name, picture and comments. the comments are array. basically i have 10 users, with different comments, i want to count how many comments on per user and display it on the html..

i have tried this

```
 db.users.aggregate({$project: { count: {$size:"$comments"}}})
```

it counts the comments per user of all user... how can i output this on the html? and how can i just perform this command on 1 user? not to all user... thanks!

Comment: why not something like `$db.users.findOne({_id: usersId }).comments.length`

Comment: how can i get the value of it on javascript? so that i can output it on the html... thank you sir!

Comment: its working thanks! but when i tried this command on the JS, it gives me an error, it says that it cannot read the 'length' property... here's my code  `var countComment = TestData.findOne({_id: 'ObjectId("57cdf6b3fbccf41198389aca")' }).comments.length;`

Answer (score 0):

For finding the number of comments made by a single user, use the following command in mongoose.

```
Users.findOne({_id: ObjectId("57cdf6b3fbccf41198389aca")}, function(err, user) {
     if(err) {
       //handle error
     } else if(!user) {
       //no user found
     } else {
       //user found
       if(user.comments) {
           console.log('user comments length', user.comments.length);
       } else {
           console.log('no user comments');
       }
     }
})
```